# sikuli, how to capture screen where the script did not run well

Tags: python, eclipse, automation, sikuli

Sikuli, how to capture screen where the script did not run well where I got an error from the script execution in Sikuli, I'm doing the Eclipse script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this to capture a screenshot:

```
def takeScreenShot(application):
 img = capture(SCREEN) # img is an image file .png in temp folder now
 ts = time.time()
 st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
 if not os.path.exists('PATH'):
  os.makedirs('')
 shutil.move(img, 'PATH\\%(appName)s\\%(timeStamp)s.png' %{"appName": application, "timeStamp": st})
```

You can call this method as a part of a try catch block.